# Use the other columns value if a condition is met Panda

Tags: python, pandas

**Assuming I have the following table:**

```
+----+---+---+
| A  | B | C |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | 1 | 3 |
|  2 | 2 | 7 |
| 6  | 3 | 2 |
| -1 | 9 | 0 |
|  2 | 1 | 3 |
| -8 | 8 | 2 |
|  2 | 1 | 9 |
+----+---+---+
```

if column A's value is Negative, update column B's value by the value of column C. if not do nothing

**This is the desired output:**

```
+----+---+---+
| A  | B | C |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | 1 | 3 |
|  2 | 2 | 7 |
| 6  | 3 | 2 |
| -1 | 0 | 0 |
|  2 | 1 | 3 |
| -8 | 2 | 2 |
|  2 | 1 | 9 |
+----+---+---+
```

I've been trying the following code but it's not working

```
#not working
result.loc(result["A"] < 0,result['B'] = result['C'].iloc[0])
```

Comment: `df['B'].where(df.A.ge(0), df.C)`

Comment: Using `where` is correct, but this might have been what you were trying to do: `result.loc[result['A']<0,'B'] = result.loc[result['A']<0,'C']`. But as you can clearly see, `.where` is cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

result.B[result.A < 0] = result.C

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['A'] < 0, 'B'] = df['C']
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)